# extract string and fill to other columns in r

Tags: r, string, substring, extract

I have a data frame in r looks like this.

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4))

df[,1]<-c("472=20140112224524497,5752=122524,223=ZHRR6,69=0,"
      ,"472=20140112224606569,223=BNCG6,315=CC26R,69=22,"
      ,"50=986,472=20140112224607924,223=ZHCG6,69=98,"
      ,"66=2315,472=20140112224502367,379=2016,223=CMCG9,69=274,")
```

What I want is to extract strings from the first column and fill up to the 2nd to 4th column for each row.

column 2, i need strings between 472= and the first "," after that.

column 3, i need strings between 223= and the first "," after that.

column 4, i need strings between 69= and the first "," after that.

The data has no patterns and the value could be either integer or alphabets.

My current code is:

```
df[,2:4]<-c(unlist(ex_between(df$X1, c('472='), c(','), extract=TRUE)) 
          ,unlist(ex_between(df$X1, c('223='), c(','), extract=TRUE)) 
          ,unlist(ex_between(df$X1, c('69='), c(','), extract=TRUE)))
```

This code works. However, it is very slow, since I have more than 1 million rows per day, and 12 columns needs to fill.

I really appreciate it if someone can help to revise and speed up the process.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: try strsplit with comma for each row, either you need apply also, or it works rowwise itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` specifying the pattern to match numbers (`\\d+`) that follow a regex lookbehind a number (`\\d`) followed by `=`

```
library(stringr)
df[-1] <- do.call(rbind, str_extract_all(df$X1, "(?<=\\d\\=)[^,]+"))
```

---

Or using `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (2:4) := tstrsplit(X1, "\\d+=|,")[c(FALSE, TRUE)]]
```